# How to get ActionParameters in OnResultExecuted action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

*I want action parameters in the above action filter method. please help me*

```
Public Overrides Sub OnResultExecuted(filterContext As ResultExecutedContext)
   Dim actionParameter = filterContext.ActionParameters(parameterName)
 End Sub


 var params={};
 params.Comments=getvaluebyid("TxtComment");
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/ControllerName/ActionName',
         async: true,
         data: $.toJSON(params),
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: how to get action parameters in OnResultExecuted action filter

Comment: In C# . `foreach (var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters){response.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}", parameter.Key,parameter.Value));}`

Comment: filterContext.ActionParameters not valid in OnResultExecuted

Answer (score 0):

You can get Action parameters by doing this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
       var controllerActionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor as System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor;
       ParameterDescriptor[]pdes= controllerActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
       foreach (var item in pdes)
       {
           var parameterName = item.ParameterName;
           var parameterType=item.ParameterType;
       }
    }
```

For getting values, you can do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Id"]// where "Id" is the key, you can use index here too.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need parameter values. for above code i can get parameter name only.

Comment: In my case HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString is empty and HttpContext.Current.Request.Form also empty.

Comment: type: "POST",
                                    url: '/ControllerName/ActionName',
                                    async: true,
                                    data: $.toJSON(Params),
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Comment: It is better if you write that ajax method in your question, so It will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this problem. Find the below solution for getting json results. For below method we need to pass request.

```
private string GetJsonContents(System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request)
{
  string JsonContents = string.Empty;
  try
    {
     using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
      {
      using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
      {
       receiveStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
       JsonContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
      }
     }
    }
    catch
    {
     enter code here
    }
    return JsonContents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
Here is my workaround.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {   var myValue = ((MyClass)((JsonResult)filterContext.Result).Data).Value; }
```

I hope this helps!